# unable to use the methods of one java class into the second class using a package

Tags: java, jsp

Actually, my task is to make java bean classes inside a same package and use them into  JSP (java server pages).

Below is what i am doing.

**Package name: mypack**
**1st class name: UserBean.java** (contains all getters and setters methods)
**2nd class name: Databean.java** (contains the methods to interact with database)
**d:\java:** jdk1.5 and tomcat, both are in this folder.

**UserBean.java:**  I want to use the setter and getter methods of this class to set and get the values.
**DataBean.java:** I want to use this class's methods to interact with MS Access database like fetch, update, delete etc. For these actions, i want to instantiate UserBean class object into DataBean Class to set and get the values of DataBean class.

How i am compiling?

**d:\java\mypack> set path=d:\java\jdk1.5\bin**
 
**d:\java\mypack>javac UserBean.java**

But when i instantiate UserBean class's object inside the DataBean Class, i get the error that i have already mentioned.

**d:\java\mypack>javac DataBean.java**
here i get that above error message

to resolve this issue, i modified the compiling line a little bit:

**d:\java\mypack>javac -classpath .. DataBean.java**
this works and successfully generates the class file

For now, both classes are being compiled successfully. There is another issue now and is described below.

```
package mypack;
**//UserBean.java**
public class UserBean{
       String username;    //an attribute of UserBean Class
       String password;    //an attribute of UserBean Class

public UserBean(){} //Default Constructor of UserBean Class
public void setUsername(String username){ this.username = username;   }//setter      method
       public String getUsername(){return username; } //getter method
}

package mypack;
**//DataBean.java**
public class DataBean{
       UserBean user = new UserBean();  //Instantiating UserBean class object in
       //DataBean class
       String username;     //an attribute of DataBean Class

       public DataBean(){}  //Default Constructor of UserBean Class
       public String getUsernameTwo(){return user.getUsername(); } //gettter method
}
```

On jsp page, i instantiated two objects

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*, mypack.*"%> //importing packages
<html>
<body>
<%
UserBean u = new UserBean(); *//UserBean class object u has been instantiated*
DataBean d = new DataBean(); //DataBean class object d has been instantiated

u.setUsername("John");  //username has been set as john
out.println(u.getUsername()); //gets the string john, and prints it successfully 
(prints: John)

out.println(d.getUsernameTwo()); //Does'nt print John, but prints null 
                                 //**(it should print john too but it doesnt)**
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question/questions?

Comment: **@Mikael Hallne** I've two classes. **UserBean.java & DataBean.java**. It should work the way, i mean, if i set a value in **UserBean class**, i should be able to get that particular value in **DataBean class** by instantiating **UserBean Class object** inside **DataBean Clas**. I should be able to use all the methods of **UserBean Class from DataBean class**. Both of my classes are in the same packcage. I'm doing this to make it work with JSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method getUsernameTwo() returns the user name of a UserBean that has been created in the constructor of DataBean. This UserBean instance is not the same UserBean object as the one that you instantiated in your JSP.

That's like opening two bottles, putting a message in one of the bottles, and looking inside the other bottle hoping to find the message you put in the first one. It doesn't work with bottles, and doesn't work with Java objects either, because Java objects are somewhat like real objects.

One thing you could do is to make the DataBean use a UserBean passed in its cnstructor:

```
public class DataBean{
    private UserBean user;       

    public DataBean(UserBean user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUsernameTwo() {
        return user.getUsername(); 
    }
}
```

And in your JSP:

```
<%
UserBean u = new UserBean();
DataBean d = new DataBean(u);

u.setUsername("John");
out.println(u.getUsername());
out.println(d.getUsernameTwo());
%>
```

It seems you haven't grasped basic OO concepts yet. I would advise starting tutorials on basic Java and OO first, before playing with JSPs.

Comment: **@JB Nizet** can you please do a little example for me by making two classes. That would be great

Comment: **@JB Nizet ** I'm new to Java and Jsp. This is what i want to do. Here's a link http://javux.com/JavuxDocs/Tutorials/JavaBeansJSPs_JT39.html

Comment: **@JB Nizet** thanks for your response. The problem is, we cannot make a constructor in java bean class that receives any argument. It violates the rule of java bean class. Isn't it??

Comment: Strictly speaking, a JavaBean must have a no-arg contructor. That doesn't prevent to have another constructor taking an argument, though. And in this case, not having a no-arg constructor doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that in DataBean Class you create another instace of UserBean, that is not the same with the one that you create in the jsp page.

In class DataBean try this:

```
UserBean user = (UserBean)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("u");
```

"u" - is your instance of UserBean that you want to use.

Comment: i made all the string type attributes of both classes private but still not working. I mean compilation was successful but d.getUsernameTwo() is still displaying null.

Comment: The OP is not even using JSF, and hasn't put anything in the session.

Comment: **@cristi** can you please do a little example for me by making two classes. That would be great

Comment: **cristi** i am new to java & jsp. A small example would be great